# Adblocker blocks my Angular website (Google Analytics)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I have been informed by a company that they cannot visit my Angular-powered website since I am relying on Google Analytics. It is their policy to block Trackers and Ads.

Since my website is fully made in Angular and one of the dependencies is actually Google Analytics, I was wondering whether I could implement somehow a fallback for visitors that have this type of Adblocker turned on.

Moreover, could I somehow disable the dependency injection when the user blocks it. The core of the problem are the dependencies `angulartics`

**My app.js looks as follows:**

```
angular.module('mywebsite', [
  'angulartics', 'angulartics.google.analytics',
  ]
)
```

**and my index.html**

```
<script src="/bower_components/angulartics/dist/angulartics.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angulartics-google-analytics/dist/angulartics-google-analytics.min.js"></script>
```

Can I rewrite is such that if these scripts get blocked that they get removed as a dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try renaming `angulartics-google-analytics.min.js` to `angulartics-ga.min.js` , it may help you.